# Call a C function that accepts a const pointer to struct from Nim

Tags: ffi, nim-lang

I am using GNU argparse from Nim using its foreign function interface.
In <argp.h> there is function argp_parse which is declared as follows

```
extern error_t argp_parse (const struct argp *__restrict __argp,
           int __argc, char **__restrict __argv,
           unsigned __flags, int *__restrict __arg_index,
           void *__restrict __input);
```

the tricky part are the const and __restrict before the first parameter, in Nim I wrote this code

```
type
  ArgpChild {.importc: "struct argp_child"} = object
    argp : ptr[Argp]
    flags : cint
    header : cstring
    group : cint

  Argp* {.importc: "struct argp", header: "<argp.h>"} = object
    options : ptr[ArgpOption]
    parser : pointer #proc (key : cint, arg: cstring, state : ptr[ArgpState]) : Error
    args_doc : cstring
    doc : cstring
    children : ArgpChild 
    help_filter : pointer #proc(key : int, text : cstring, input: pointer) : cstring
    argp_domain : cstring

  ArgpOption* {.importc: "struct argp_option"} = object
    name : cstring
    key : cint
    arg : cstring
    flags : cint
    doc : cstring
    group : cint

  ArgpState {.importc: "struct argp_state"} = object
    input : pointer

  Error* = enum 
    ARGP_KEY_ARG = 0,
    ARGP_ERR_UNKNOWN = 7, 
    ARGP_KEY_END = 0x1000001

proc argp_parse*(argp : Argp, argc : cint, argv : cstringArray, flags: cuint, arg_index: ptr[cint], input : pointer) : Error {.importc: "argp_parse".}
```

the problem is that the Nim compiler (with c backend) generates this line for argp_parse function (note the missing const and __restrict keywords before the first parameter)

```
N_CDECL(Error177010, argp_parse)(struct argp* argp0, int argc0, NCSTRING* argv0, unsigned int flags0, int* argindex0, void* input0);
```

then, when gcc handles that file, it complains yelling "conflicting types for ‘argp_parse’", I guess this is because it finds two definitions of the same functions with different types in the first parameter.

Is there any way to force the Nim compiler to add the const (and maybe __restrict) keyword before a function parameter when using the c backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nim will support a `restrict` pragma in the future that will allow you to specify such parameters. This is evident from the latest [todo.txt](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/08a6f3fc67f1bac78c47a241c94f936d7fbd5108/todo.txt#L82) in the Nim's repository.

In the meantime, there is one possible work-around for this. Instead of using the `importc` pragma, you can use the `emit` pragma:

```
proc argp_parse*(argp: Argp,
                 argc: cint,
                 argv: cstringArray,
                 flags: cuint,
                 arg_index: ptr[cint],
                 input: pointer): Error =
  {.emit: "argp_parse(`argp`, `argc`, `argv`, `flags`, `arg_index`, `input`);".}
```

This will create a regular non-imported proc that just forwards the call the `argp_parse` function.

Answer (score 0):

The correct fix is simply to add `header`:

```
when defined case_bad: #  error: conflicting types for 'strlen'
  proc c_strlen(a: cstring): csize_t {.importc: "strlen".}
else: # ok
  proc c_strlen(a: cstring): csize_t {.importc: "strlen", header: "<string.h>".}
echo c_strlen("abc")
```